# CDI inside OSGI - it doesn't see bean

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, glassfish, osgi

I have two OSGI bundles:
The first contains: service, servlet, pojo
The second contains: consumer (of the service).

FACTS:
A) I inject service (bundle 1) to consumer (bundle 2) via CDI (@OSGiService) - everything is OK. 
B) I inject pojo to servlet via CDI (manually using beanManager.getBeans,beanManager.resolve) - everything is OK.
C) I inject pojo to service via CDI (manually using beanManager.getBeans,beanManager.resolve) - Error - can't locate the bean.

The reason why I use manual injection is that that I couldn't get it to work with @Inject and started googling. And I found [this](https://www.java.net/forum/topic/glassfish/glassfish/using-cdi-inside-osgi-bundle)

> CDI allows injection into non-component classes, but the instances
>   must still be created by CDI. Your activator is instantiated by OSGi
>   framework and CDI has no way to hook into that process. You can
>   programmatically get hold of the CDI injection manager and request an
>   instance from it instead of using @Inject in your main class.

I think that (C) must work, because instance is created via CDI but it doesn't. Where is mistake?

EDIT: Glassfish4, weld, apache felix

Source code of 3 bundles (1 bundle with interface) can be downloaded [here](http://webtoweb.ru/Source.zip). There are two servlets:
The first one can be accessed /testme1/NewServlet1 (bundle 1)
The second one can be accessed /testme2/NewServlet2 (bundle 2)

Comment: Can you post your code somewhere (github). This sounds like a small error in your code or config.

Comment: @Christian Schneider Thank you for your time. I couldn't post original code as I don't have rights, so I created three mini projects. http://webtoweb.ru/Source.zip. Urls:...:8080/testme1/NewServlet1, :8080/testme2/NewServlet2 the problem is the same - java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not locate a bean of type com.test1.Pojo when you open /testme2/NewServlet2

Comment: I was not yet able to look into it in detail. What I found was that you build your Manifest by hand. This is very error prone. Better try to use the maven bundle plugin.

Comment: Btw. Why don´t you use annotations for injecting the pojo into the service in C. This should work.

Comment: @Christian Schneider I tried and with annotations - the result is the same. To tell the truth I started with annotations.

Comment: @Christian Schneider Do you have experience with weld-osgi. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22878449/how-to-bootstrap-weld-osgi-version-2-in-se-application - question is very important and I think it will be interesting for many developers as it's very difficult to write a bootstrap for weld-osig.

Comment: Not directly. I used pax-cdi a bit. Which is described as the successor for weld-osgi. Pax-cdi offers the OSGi adaption for weld or open web beans.

Comment: @Christian Schneider The problem is that we use GF and it uses weld. So I don't want to use two frameworks at the same time. Weld as I remember is a reference implementation of CDI.

Comment: Yes. Weld should be fine for CDI itself but it does not contain the adaption to OSGi. This is what weld-osgi does but I heard it would be discontinued. You are right though that pax-xdi might not fit with GF. I use karaf most of the time where it is a good fit.

Comment: And check your mojarra version, i had some problems with the one bundled in Glassfish 4, after update it everything worked again