# How to bootstrap weld-osgi version 2 in SE application

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, osgi, jboss-weld

It's really not funny. There is no information in internet how to run weld-osgi second version (2.1.2.final) in se app. Instructions for ver 1 don't work.

**Let the developers be ashamed that they didn't provide necessary samples. I wrote them [here](https://community.jboss.org/message/866857).**

So, I have and OSGi activator and I want to get beans from it. In GF4 I used this:

```
private BeanManager getBeanManager() throws NamingException
{
  try{
   InitialContext initialContext = new InitialContext();
            return (BeanManager)  initialContext.lookup("java:comp/BeanManager");
   }
  catch (NamingException e) {
            System.out.println("Couldn't get BeanManager through JNDI");
            return null;
   }
}
```

But in SE application I can't get it through JNDI.
Also I tried:

```
Weld weld=new Weld();
BeanManager beanManager=weld.getBeanManager();
```

But at the second line I get

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Singleton is not set. Is
>   your Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader() set correctly?

How can I use CDI starting from activator? What is my mistake?

EDIT:
What I did - I found two source code of two programs that use it, but it's really no so easy to write on their base (at least for me). The first is [here](https://gitorious.org/arquillian/arquillian/source/f2941efa2ac5dfafe39a4fd8919ee1a022351f5d%3acontainer-weld-embedded/src/main/java/org/jboss/arquillian/weld/WeldSEContainer.java#L31-47) and the second is [here](http://alvinalexander.com/java/jwarehouse/glassfish/web/weld-integration/src/main/java/org/glassfish/weld/WeldDeployer.java.shtml)

Comment: Just a guess: did you called `weld.initialize()`? https://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/environments.html#d0e5725

Comment: We have a Java SE app with Weld and starting it with `java org.jboss.weld.environment.se.StartMain <args>` works well (we don't have any OSGi).

Comment: @palacsint About - weld.initialize() in this version there is no such method. What about org.jboss.weld.environment.se.StartMain I tried to run it and everything is ok. But as far as I understand it's used witout osgi as weld-se is not bundle. With osgi as I think weld-osgi must be used.

Comment: `weld-osgi-bundle` does not contain any `Bundle-Activator` header, I have no idea how it should be started. It might be similar than in former versions.

Comment: Anyway, is `StartMain` solved the problem? If yes I guess I should  write it as an answer.

Comment: @palacsint You are right - it doesn't contain activator. So I think it must be initialized. I am reading sources now. I don't think StartMain is right.

Comment: @palacsint I edited the question. If you are really interested in it please support this question.

Answer (score 0):

The weld-osgi subproject is not supported anymore with Weld 2. Instead, integration with OSGi is provided using the Pax CDI project.

Pax CDI documentation can be found here: https://ops4j1.jira.com/wiki/display/PAXCDI/Pax+CDI

Additional information can be found at:
- http://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest/users-guide/cdi.html
- https://github.com/weld/core/blob/master/examples/osgi/README.md

Comment: Don't you know glassfish uses weld-osgi or pax cdi and why?